# java.rmi.RemoteExeption: CORBA NO_RESPONSE root cause analysis

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, rmi, corba

We have an EJB application deployed on WebSphere 8.5, We are getting the following exception on console,

```
java.rmi.Exception:CORBA NO_RESPONSE 0x4942fb01 Maybe: nested exception is:
RESPONSE: Request 221370 timed out vmcid: IBM minor code: B01 Completed maybe
```

I can also see the root cause of exception as below:

```
caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_RESPONSE: Request timed out vmcid: B01 Completed maybe
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.getCallStream(Connection.java:2493)
```

The effect of it is end user is unable to connect to the application.

Upon doing some analysis: I found out that main reason could be the connection pool settings.
So Can someone please help me on following:

- possible root causes of above exception
- possible way to fix this exception

Comment: can you paste the full stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request timed out` means that the EJB request timed out (default 180 seconds): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/uorb_rsetg.html

This may have many causes, but in general, it's best to analyze the performance of the EJB backend service (e.g. garbage collection, long response times due to a database, etc.). Here is a place to start on investigating general WAS performance problems: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Recipes-WAS_Traditional_Recipes-General_WAS_Traditional_Performance_Problem.html

A key item is step 8 which gathers thread dumps and basic OS statistics during the problem. If you are stuck analyzing that data, you may open an IBM support request with that MustGather data.

Comment: Increase ORB request timeout worked for me, thanks.